# Number of edges of a graph when distance of vertices is known

Tags: graph-theory

I saw this interesting problem, I did my best so solve it but I failed.

In the graph $G = (V,E)$ , if  $|V| = 10$ and number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of vertices equals to **72** such that $d(x,y) \ge 2$, then how many edges G has? the answer is one of the following choices.

1. 9
2. 18
3. 28
4. 36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the total number of ordered pairs of vertices? Clearly $10\times 10=100$. What is the total number of pairs of type $d(x,y)=0$? Clearly, 10. Now what is the number of pairs with $d(x,y)=1$? It is $100-10-72=18$. Each edge $xy$ is counted twice in this number: once as $d(x,y)=1$ and once as $d(y,x)=1$. So the number of edges is $18/2=9$.

Comment: Thank you very much, nice solution.